# Reason and functioning of split NTFS permissions

Tags: windows, powershell, ntfs, file-permissions, acl

On a fresh formatted non-system NTFS volume of type hard disk media (unpartitionable USB thumb drive is different) under Windows 10, the NTFS ACEs are as follows (*Get-Acl*):

```
FileSystemRights  : -536805376
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : InheritOnly

FileSystemRights  : Modify, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : 268435456
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : InheritOnly

FileSystemRights  : 268435456
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Administrators
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : InheritOnly

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Administrators
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Users
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : -1610612736
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Users
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : InheritOnly
```

The corresponding SDDL-string is (also from *Get-Acl*): `O:SYG:SYD:AI(A;OICIIO;SDGXGWGR;;;AU)(A;;0x1301bf;;;AU)(A;;FA;;;SY)(A;OICIIO;GA;;;SY)(A;OICIIO;GA;;;BA)(A;;FA;;;BA)(A;;0x1200a9;;;BU)(A;OICIIO;GXGR;;;BU)`

My question is *not* about the meaning of the ACEs. I know, that each pair of ACEs are practically twins, one noninherited for the root folder of the volume, one inheriting only for subfolders and files. I also know about the meaning of the numbers after some *FileSystemRights*, there are many sources in the web about them: The permissions of two "twins" are practically the same, the only difference is, that the noninheriting permissions use "File" rights, while the inheriting permissions use "Generic" rights (you see the latter ones as Gs in the SDDL-String). The only reason, why the latter ones are represented as number, is because no appropriate enumeration names exist.

Rather, my questions are as follows:

(1) Why does Windows automagically split the original four permissions into eight (two of a pair), after such a fresh format?

(2) Why doesn't the GUI (-> *Properties* -> *Security* tab) reflect this split, but PowerShell, *icacls* and *cacls* do?

(3) Why does Windows inherit *both* permissions of a pair to child file system objects, although only each *one* of these permissions are inheritable?

I have one additional question. If you add an arbitrary ACE per -> *Properties* -> *Security* tab to such an ACL, save, and after that, remove this additional ACE immediately again, the ACEs of the freshly formatted drive suddenly look like you would have expected from the beginning (*Get-Acl* again):

```
FileSystemRights  : Modify, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Administrators
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : BUILTIN\Users
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None
```

Corresponding SDDL-String (*Get-Acl*): `O:SYG:SYD:PAI(A;OICI;0x1301bf;;;AU)(A;OICI;FA;;;SY)(A;OICI;FA;;;BA)(A;OICI;0x1200a9;;;BU)`

(4) Why does Windows automagically merge the split permissions into one again, in the moment, you add an ACE, even if you remove it afterwards?